# Failed to deploy Simple Spring MVC project to AWS Tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, gradle

I am recently starting a new Java web project, and is trying out the well-acclaimed Spring MVC Framework. My coding experience with Java servlet dated about 6 years ago so I am a little rusty. After 2 days of studying and testing around, I failed to deploy a simple Hello World app (built with Gradle) to a testing cloud (AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Linux and Tomcat 8). More importantly, I can't get my head around with how things really connected given all the documentations I found online.

Here are a few questions which I couldn't find definite answers:

1. How do I decide which Spring framework dependencies I should include in my build.gradle? Examples online are suggesting different things. Currently my dependencies settings are

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.4.RELEASE'
       compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.7.4'
       compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
       compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
   }
   ```

   and my source files are only two simple Java files:

   {project_root}/src/main/java/test/Greeter.java

   ```
   package test;

   public class Greeter {
     public String sayHello() {
       return "Hello world!";
     }
   }
   ```

   {project_root}/src/main/java/test/HelloWorld.java

   ```
   package test;

   public class HelloWorld {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Greeter greeter = new Greeter();        
           System.out.println(greeter.sayHello());
       }
   }
   ```

   gradle build is successful so far.
2. Where should I store my JSP files (Views)?
3. How should I configure `web.xml`, and any other XMLs that are required to tell Tomcat where the files are located? Where should I store these XMLs?
4. How should I configure `build.gradle` to compile a .war file that has all the resources needed to run my Spring web app on Tomcat? My current `build.gradle` is as below:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'war'


   repositories {
       mavenLocal()
       mavenCentral()
   }

   sourceCompatibility = 1.8
   targetCompatibility = 1.8

   war {
       version = '0.4'
       baseName = 'collaborative-system'
   }  
   project.webAppDirName = 'webapp'

   dependencies {
       compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.4.RELEASE'
       compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.7.4'
       compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
       compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
   }

   sourceSets {
       main {
           java {
               srcDir 'src'
           }
       }
   }


   task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
       gradleVersion = '2.3'
   }
   ```

Server is now showing a 404 page with the .war file built.

Comment: If you're starting out with Spring, use Spring Boot (which eliminates the need for most configuration) and [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io), which will generate a Maven or Gradle build for you with all the necessary dependencies.

Comment: I am also new to this stuff.  Here is a link to my first Spring project, which may serve as an example: http://djangofan.github.io/spring-boot-mortgage-calculator/

Comment: @chrylis Thanks, Spring Boot seems like a good solution, I've followed their tutorials and managed to gradle build a .war file with Spring Boot dependencies. Yet I'm still having trouble to deploy it to AWS (404, still). Is there a need to configure web.xml when using Spring Boot? Or, am I missing any configs on AWS? Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Don't build a war. Build a jar and forget about having to worry about setting up a container.

Comment: @chrylis I need to build a webapp with Jsp, HTML and javascript. I don't think jar serves the purpose.

Comment: I do it all the time, including for one application with about twenty Maven modules plus dependencies. See [the docs for the Gradle plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html) or just use Initializr to create a template project that has the repackage settings and `main` included.

Comment: @chrylis thanks. I used Initializr to create a spring web project template, and when i run `java -jar` on terminal, it throws a `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container` exception. Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: @chrylis ahh I found the issue mentioned in my recent comment. It was because I had a Tomcat server running on my machine. Didn't realise that Spring Boot app has an embedded Tomcat already. But if the servlet container is embedded, how do I deploy my app to an external server?

Comment: You just run it. I use Cloud Foundry (Pivotal Web Services) and just upload the jar and I'm done. If you absolutely have to use an existing external container because your organization is stuck in 2005, you'll need to follow the steps to produce a war (Boot can generate your initializer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some understandings one must have regarding Spring Framework and Spring Boot:

1. Spring Boot is a tool that makes it easy to create a Spring based applications. It helps you include all the dependencies needed, auto configure your project, embed a servlet container such as Tomcat, Jetty and etc. In short, it helps you start up without having to configure everything. For beginners, it's almost a must-have. (Thanks to the suggestion from @chrylis).
2. A `.jar` file is a self-contained executable build. Spring Boot makes it easy to run your application without having to configure a servlet on your machine. The Spring documentation has stated:

   > This jar is handy because it includes all the other dependencies and things like your web server inside the archive. You can give anybody this one .jar and they can run your entire Spring application with no fuss: no build tool required, no setup, no web server configuration, etc: just java -jar ...your.jar.
3. If you need to deploy your application to an external servlet like I do (for eg. to AWS), you will have to build a `.war` file. The difference between `.war` and `.jar` is that `.war` does not include the embedded container dependency, thus allowing your own servlet container to execute the app. To convert `.jar` to `.war`, follow this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/
4. By building a `.war` file you also need configuration to tell your own servlet container which class to run on startUp. Traditionally, we use `web.xml` but for servlet 3.0+, Spring has replaced this with `SpringBootServletInitializer`. It's a handy class that binds your application to servlet. Just do the following:

   ```
   import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
   import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

   public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
          return application.sources(SpringBootAwsApplication.class);
      }
   }
   ```

   SpringBootAwsApplication is the main class that contains the `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

I recommend anyone who is encountering issues with Spring Boot to **SOLELY** refer to the official documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/. Refer to other examples online only if you can't find relevant information on the docs.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give quite enough information.  I am going to guess that once you deployed your .war file, your tried to access it at:

```
http://localhost:8080/collaborative-system/viewname
```

Assuming that is correct, you must keep in mind that you need a Controller class that is annotated correctly and returns a string that matches the view name that you have in your `WEB-INF/jsp/` folder.  If you don't do that, then its not really a Spring project at all.

Comment: I'm using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk as my testing server. I deployed the war file directly on the console, and when assessing the URL, it returns a 404 page.

Comment: would you provide me an example how do I construct such Controller class? Where do I return the view name, and which annotation to be included? thanks.